# Getopt - adding case for both missing option and missing non-option argument

Tags: c, getopt

I'm making a part of a bigger program, this part takes in information from a text file or a feed of standard input, the nature of this information depends on what option is added to the program. With no text file added as a non-option argument, the program should read from stdin.

For example:

**fizzle.exe -a textfile.txt**    reads textfile.exe in the way prescriped by the option -a

**fizzle.exe -a** reads stdin in the way prescribed by the option a

What I havent gotten to work yet is:

**fizzle.exe textfile.txt**    reading textfile.txt(or stdin if no proper text file) in the way prescribed by giving no option

This is my code:

```
while ((option = getopt(argc,argv, ":a:b:")) != -1 ) {

    FILE *pointerFile = filereader(optarg);

    switch(option) {
        case 'a' :
            optionchosen = 0;
            counter(optionchosen,pointerFile,argv);
            break;

        case 'b' :
            optionchosen = 1;
            counter(optionchosen,pointerFile,argv);
            break;


        case ':' :
            counter(optionchosen,pointerFile,argv);
            break;          

    }
}
```

I cant figure out how to add a case to this switch that is activated by giving no option, but still works with or without the non-option argument(filename).

Comment: Can you please post the particular question in a well formatted way that does not look like filename jive? What is the role of `brackets.exe`?

Comment: I cleaned up I hope it helps.

The textfile provides information needed for some calculations. The reading, and the calculations both work perfectly. I didnt elaborate on the role of that file because I felt it would waste time, confuse and distract from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can do exactly what you want to do with `getopt`, and more, you just need to adjust your logic slightly. Specifically, you can setup `getopt` so that:

```
fizzle.exe                        /* reads from stdin   */
fizzle.exe -a                     /* reads from stdin   */
fizzle.exe -a textfile.txt        /* reads textfile.txt */
fizzle.exe textfile.txt           /* reads textfile.txt */
```

Here is a short example of implementing the above logic around the `-a` option. The last case also specifies that, if give, the first unhandled option after all options are given will also be taken as the filename to read.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* for getopt */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int opt;
    char *fn = NULL;
    FILE *pointerFile = stdin;  /* set 'stdin' by default */

    while ((opt = getopt (argc, argv, "a::b:")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
            case 'a' :  /* open file if given following -a on command line */
                if (!optarg) break;     /* if nothing after -a, keep stdin */
                fn = argv[optind - 1];
                pointerFile = fopen (fn, "r");
                break;
            case 'b' :; /* do whatever */
                break;
            default :   /* ? */
                fprintf (stderr, "\nerror: invalid or missing option.\n");
        }
    }
    /* handle any arguments that remain from optind -> argc
     * for example if 'fizzle.exe textfile.txt' given, read from
     * textfile.txt instead of stdin.
     */
    if (pointerFile == stdin && argc > optind) {
        fn = argv[optind++];
        pointerFile = fopen (fn, "r");
    }

    printf ("\n fizzle.txt reads : %s\n\n", pointerFile == stdin ? "stdin" : fn);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/output**

```
$ ./bin/optfizzle

 fizzle.exe reads : stdin

$ ./bin/optfizzle -a

 fizzle.exe reads : stdin

$ ./bin/optfizzle -a somefile.txt

 fizzle.exe reads : somefile.txt

$ ./bin/optfizzle someotherfile.txt

 fizzle.exe reads : someotherfile.txt
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I removed two questions I resolved myself. Thank you for this clean solution, I understand how it solves my problem and I have edited it to fit in my program(where filereading and calculations are done separately) :)

Answer (score 1):

Forget the leading `:` in your **getopt** string; just use getopt for options.  After you're done with them, the remaining elements on the command line, if any, are found between `argv[optind]` and `argv[argc]`.

If the caller provides no filename, use `/dev/stdin` as the default, or `stdin` from **stdlib.h**.  No need to require the user to provide a `-` to stand in for standard input.

Answer (score 0):

Programs using `getopt` should, by convention, read from stdin if you give it a `-` as an input parameter.

As a side note, you should always have a case for `?` (or a `default` case).

Here is an example of reading the remaining arguments, place it below the big `while` loop where you process all `getopt` flags:

```
int i;
for (i = optind; i < argc; ++i)
    printf("Non-option argument %s\n", argv[i]);
```

Comment: Okay.

But is there a case I could add to the program to get it to work the way I want it to without a -?

Comment: Normally `getopt` is only used for switches, filenames are usually taken from the arguments which are left over and not parsed by `getopt`.

Comment: Oh thats interesting.

Comment: @Flowdorio `man getopt` will describe this in greater detail.

Comment: Do you have any example of how you would do this without inluding the filename as the optarg?